# TeamSQL unpublish a result

Tags: postgresql, teamsql

I was testing a program called TeamSQL. In it one can share the result of a query with a link. I shared the wrong result and i would like to delete that page as it contains sensitive data.
Example result: https://share.teamsql.io/c35d45aa-be8c-45ba-8581-bf1c2c39fb90
Ps. this link will expire in 23 hours.

Is there a way to delete a result page like that? 
I cant find how to do it on the TeamSQL website?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, check out the File menu, "Shared Results" will help you for that.

[image]

[image]